# How to update DataGrid in Silverlight when Property in ObserveableCollection changed

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, datagrid

I have a Datagrid bound to a ObserveableCollection(MyClass) source1;

MyClass has 2 Properties: string Name, int AGE

Now i have 50 MyClass Objets in the Collection, that means i have 50 rows in my datagrid.
if i want to see all rows, i have to scroll around and that is ok!!

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e){
int index = dataGrid.SelectedIndex;
obsCollection[index].Name="AAAAA";
}
```

Everytime i click on a row, i would like that on that row Name is changed to string Name="AAAAAA";

The whole thing works if i scroll up or down and the row is not anymore shown in the datagrid. Somehow the row gets updatet when it is out of sight and later shown. When i scroll around and come back to that row and the row is now SHOWN again in datagrid, the value has been updatet.

But i want an instant change!! Just select/click on the row and Name is changed to "AAAAAA".
I do not want to have that row out of sight, to get an update.

edit: i can not use datagrid.itemsssource=null; because i would get infinite loop on selectionchanged

Comment: Do your items (MyClass) implement INotifyPropertyChanged? That is an requirement for the UI to see the changes on the item itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generic type of ObservableCollection need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). For example you have collection of `Employee` and want the UI to update automatically when some employee's value changed.

1. You need to create Employee class and implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

   ```
   public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       public string FirstName
       {
           get { return this._firstName; }
           set 
           {        
               this._firstName = value;
               this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
           }
       }

       public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

       private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
       {
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
           {
               PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use Employee as generic parameter type to ObservableCollection like this `ObservableCollection<Employee>`
3. Now, when you change value of employee in ObservableCollection, the value will update to UI for you.

Comment: ah get it; public string _firstName;